ApplicationWindow - how to align content item strict between header and footer?
Simple example:
ApplicationWindow {
    header: MyHeader {
        id: myHeader
    }

    footer: MyFooter {
        id: myFooter
    }

    ListView {
        id: myListView
        anchors.fill: parent
        //Layout.fillWidth: true
        //Layout.fillHeight: true
        //anchors.top: myHeader.bottom
        //anchors.bottom: myFooter.top
        //anchors.right: parent.width
    }
}

This works but listview's items are visible under footer and header component. How to position listview so it will be strict between header and footer? Tried Layout.fill* and anchor directly to header and footer but nothing works.

strictly speaking, all the content inside ApplicationWindow is located between the header and footer. Can you specify the problem more precisely?

From the documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html

Note: Views do not enable clip automatically. If the view is not clipped by another item or the screen, it will be necessary to set clip: true in order to have the out of view items clipped nicely.

